Difference Between scp and ssh-copy-id?
So ssh-copy-id is a script while scp is just an ssh command. What's the difference between them? Both seem to connect to the remote via SSH and then transfer keys to that remote. To me, they appear to do the same thing?


So ssh-copy-id is a script while scp is just an ssh command

Not sure what you mean with "is just an ssh command"; scp is a complete protocol subsystem that gets transported through the SSH transport.

What's the difference between them?

ssh-copy-id is meant, exclusively, to add public keys to the authorized keys file on a target machine. That does not necessarily involve copying files. It appends text to a text file. The script can internally choose how to get the data to the target machine: via sftp, scp, or simply by transfer through a pipe over SSH. It furthermore figures out which file actually to modify, and does other, public-key-specific tasks.
scp is meant to generally copy files between computers.
I'd say the two tools are not very comparable.

To someone who has only ever used scp to copy SSH keys to remote systems, I'd say the two tools may appear redundant.  The insight comes from discovering that scp can do more than transfer SSH keys.

If you're using scp to copy SSH keys to remote systems, you're missing out not only on most of the features of scp, but also all the bells and whistles of ssh-copy-id; it doesn't just copy the public key, but makes sure to append it only if required.

@Kusalananda true, but in the same vein, scp alone couldn't check the location of the authorized_keys file, check the presence of the key, and if absent, append it. All scp could do is hard replace ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; whehter or not that is the right file, and whether or not that removes all previously added keys.

You may have misunderstood the intention of my previous comment. To someone who has only ever used scp and ssh-copy-id to copy SSH keys over to another machine in their private setup(s), I'm not surprised that the question of why there are seemingly two commands that do the same thing arises.
